# How do I get hold of Liferay's Hibernate Session implementation within a portlet?

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I know Liferay uses hibernate as its ORM layer.

How do I get a hold of Liferay's hibernate session so that I can write database agnostic code, within a portlet.

I'm using Liferay Portal 6.1 GA 1 ( bundled with Tomcat 7.0.23 )

Comment: I am also looking for solution for the same thing, please post it if you find anything.

Comment: What version of Liferay Portal are you using?

Comment: Liferay Portal 6.1 GA 1 ( bundled with Tomcat 7.0.23 )

Answer (score 1):

If you understand correctly, you want to write a DAL which is also database-agnostic, right?

Liferay's [Service Builder](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-build-5) is a code-generation tool which allows you to write a Data Access Layer both for new entities stored in the portal db (in fact, even portal entities' services were generated through this tool), and for tables in external databases. The generated code itself leverages Hibernate, so it should be already database agnostic. You can also write custom finder methods by passing direct SQL queries.